# Google Play Unknown Error in Live Mode

Tags: android, google-play

I am integrated google play game service in our game. It supports multiplayer, leader-board, and achievements. "Unknown Error" while sign-in was a common issue in development time. It didnt happen all the time, but 1 in a 10 times we faced this problem. We found that, we have nothing to do with that error.
After publishing that game on google play. some users are facing this problem and giving us bad review. 
Is there anything I can do about ? What should I say to users to solve this problem ? or is this our fault ? 
Anybody experiencing the same or does anyone have a solution I should try?
please help :)

Answer (score 0):

A surprising number of games forget to click the "Publish" button in the Game Services tab, which means nobody but your test accounts can access achievements or leaderboards. Go double-check that you haven't forgotten to do this.

Comment: If I dont publish the game service , then no body can't play the game .. Every thing is all right from my end. But sometimes , users are getting  this error.

Answer (score 0):

What I have figure out from my experience is that, if the app crashed or you didn't close the connections properly, then this kind of problem might happen. I am not sure about this one. But I have seen that, after closing the connection properly, my users didn't faced this problem too much !!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unable to close game data connection might be a problem ..